# Going from C# to php

Tags: c#, php

I'm going to have to learn php soon, because I need it for a new job. Up until now, i've always programmed in C#. Are there things I should know about php that are strange or different from a C# perspective? Things to look out for?

Comment: PHP is to C# as a jacket is to a car (they're very unrelated)

Comment: Have you done any ASP.NET ? If not they are completely different and no answer can cover it.

Comment: PHP is quite different from C# but if you have done ASP.NET then you should be able to use knowledge about MVC (and other design patters as well as general OOP principles) in PHP to some extent. Just pick up some framework like Zend or Symfony and it will be much easier for you to transfer from C# to PHP. Just my two cents. One more thing - get some good IDE like Eclipse (or Zend Studio if you choose to go with Zend Framework), it will save you a lot of your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They’re different programming languages. But you can do with php most things, that you can do with C#. I think they`re different in next ways:

- PHP is more simplier than C#.
- C# is full OOP language, but PHP is not.
- .NET library of classes is very big and you have all that you need. If you are using PHP, you can download classes from pear at official php site or from zend framework official site.
- If you create web application in C# you use ASP.NET MVC 2 and in PHP you can use less powerfull frameworks: symfony, zend framework, yii, kohana.

You will feel very limited with PHP after C#.

Books to read:

- PHP 5 for proffessionals.
- PHP Design patterns.

Current version of PHP is 5.3.

Comment: .... and c# is compiled whereas php is interpreted

Comment: sorry to contradict...
 * PHP is an OOP language. Why do you say it is not?
 * show me a case that you can't solve with one of the frameworks you mentioned.

Comment: No, no I said that: "C# is [full] OOP language, but PHP is not.". I mentioned [full] OOP. In php we can use functions and classes. But in C# only classes.

Comment: and all entities in C# is objects

Answer (score 5):

completely different, but a lot easier!
Grab some PHP books: [PHP MySQL books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=php+mysql&x=0&y=0&ih=8_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_2.236_183&fsc=5)

Bookmark [php.net/manual/en/](http://www.php.net/manual/en/),
Join an IRC: [irc.phpfreaks.com](http://irc.phpfreaks.com),
Learn a framework alongside: [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com),
Get a [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php)/[LAMP](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp) setup,
start on a project asap
and generally have fun.

**:) Welcome to PHP**

Answer (score 3):

The most important URL when learning PHP is definitely http://www.php.net/manual/en/

The way you use C# and PHP is different. Using PHP you will have to write more yourself, but that will give you the advantage of having more control.
The syntax itself is pretty similar, so the only thing you'll miss is the .NET framework.
The weak typing is a bit odd when coming from a strong typed environment, but you'll get the hang of it.

Unlike previous comments, PHP can be OO (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). Just read a lot and try to use good practices as you do when programming in C#.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment this comes to my mind:

- PHP is a loosly typed language (you do not have to declare variables, functions, objects prior their use)
- in PHP you need to have "function" in the declaration.
- In PHP you implement interfaces using "implements" (in C# with ":")

Comment: You don't implement classes but interfaces. Classes are being extended.

Answer (score 1):

PHP was designed specifically to make webpages, and was also put together to be as easy as possible, but without looking too far into the future or being too tied to the past.

C# was designed to do anything, and run anywhere .NET is installed.  It's put together to be as complete as possible, and draws more from the past.

PHP is easier.  If you've learned C#, don't worry; PHP should be quick for you.  Find example code so you can see how things are typically done, bookmark the PHP Manual, and dig in.

Answer (score 1):

Strangest thing about PHP for you would be: You don't need "windows" or ".net framework" to code :)

You can grab and notepad or any editor or even online one, write code, and save. Voila!

PHP is strong in OOP too (PHP 7 being amazingly cooler now).

So for web apps mainly, PHP will be all that you might be needing!

However if you have strong background in c#, you should try continuing with it.

But still give PHP 10 days, so that you realize its depths.

Answer (score 0):

As for me C# is valuable not because of language but more of a framework you can use with it.
So in that sense PHP is totally different from C#.

I've been working in PHP for some time and then moved to C# and ASP.NET.
And now there is no way someone can drag me to PHP again. I would prefer looking for another job rather that working in PHP. Nothing personal, and possibly I am too [dependent on IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147070/are-we-as-programmers-becoming-too-dependent-on-our-ides-closed) but I won't trade Visual Studio's IntelliSense, C#'s strong typing and a lot of other features I love about .NET in general.

Comment: what does this answer tell you about moving from c# to PHP? Why is C# different from PHP because it has a framework? PHP has a number of frameworks but you cannot really use a framework without reference to the language.

And what does loving VS and intellisense have to do with moving from PHP to C#?

Comment: There are many PHP frameworks - Zend, Symfony etc.

Comment: @PurplePilot, I think my answer is just a form of saying "think twice before going to the PHP-land". I know there are a lot of great PHP developers, but I think the work opportunities will be better with the language/framework you already have experience with.

Comment: @Regent I accidentally voted your comment up...

Comment: @Richard Knop, sometimes I have a feeling that there are too many [PHP frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) out there. Maybe it's just me, but I would be much more comfortable with 'one framework to rule then all'... (Impossible but still)

Comment: @Richard Knop, which one would you recommend for a beginner?

Comment: @Regent I don't want to recommend any framework because I am probably biased (I've been using ZF for a long time). I would just say it's a good thing to choose a framework with no backwards compatibility for PHP 4 and that disqualifies CI (no offence to CI but to support PHP 4 you have to sacrifice too much). Personally, I believe ZF and Symfony are the two best PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using php for more than 10 years now and learned C# when it was put on the market and use it ever since.

I think PHP is a very powerful language that can be very well structured if the programmer has driven to be organised and thorough. Undeniably PHP doesn't give you the ease of a framework (EDIT:unless you implement one). C# with .NET framework does a lot of things for you, whereas in PHP you often need to write your classes yourself.

There are gigantic class libraries on the net where you could find almost everything that you would ever want, however implementing them is sometimes more challenging compared to the highly sophisticated assemblies of .NET.

I think there is a huge market for PHP with all the UNIX platforms in use, however there is a new candidate in the horison with RUBY on Rails which has a lot mor in common with C# (I think).

Why did you decide to go with PHP?

Comment: There are many PHP frameworks - Zend, Symfony etc.

Comment: Well, I know. However I think for someone having more C# experience it is harder to consume than Ruby on Rails. However it is just my personal opinion. (edited)